# Splitting a Play! 2 application into modules

Tags: scala, playframework

I am learning Play! 2 for Scala, coming from a Django background. In Django I was used to being able to modularize a project by dividing it in various applications, each having its own models, views, controllers and assets. Does Play! allow a similar subdivision of a project or it is mandatory that everything goes under the `app` directory?

**EDIT** I already got the answer, but I will make some examples of the use of Django apps:

- The admin is a separate app
- An app can be used to define abstract models for internationalization. Actual models that need to be internationalized can inherit from them
- I created an app that defines a Facebook user model, managing the Facebook API, and exposes is to other applications that need it
- There exists a Django app to generate a sitemap programmatically
- Another Django app allows to create a robots.txt from rules stored in the database, so that one can edit robot rules from the admin interface

and so on

Comment: Why don't you just create several play applications? If they should run on the same server/domain, just put nginx or apache in front of them to handle the initial URL routing.

Comment: Well, it is less overhead to do it in the same project. Moreover, I may want to refer from one application to the other. For instance, in Django there exists one application that defines some abstract models for i18n. If you want to internationalize your models you can inherit from these ones. Similarly I created a Django application to define a user modules tied to a Facebook user, and one can use this model inside another application. Django apps are just a way to package together a set of functionality

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Maybe [sub-projects](http://www.playframework.org/documentation/2.0.2/SBTSubProjects) are what you need.
It would help if you would describe a little why you want to modularize and what a module should consist of from your point of view.

Answer (score 2):

Just a little update on the thread. From 2.1 Play supports routing mapping of sub-modules:

https://github.com/playframework/Play20/blob/master/documentation/manual/Highlights.md#allow-more-modularization-for-your-projects

Comment: The link above points to a brief explanation. Basically if you have a module which has its own routing file, you can re-use that in a higher level module by mapping that to some url.